# Shopware 6 plugin: Pagination link titles empty on subsequent pages

Tags: pagination, twig, shopware, shopware6

I'm developing a custom pagination component in Shopware 6 and running into an issue where the link titles are only populated on the first page.

In my Twig template, I have code like this to generate the pagination links:

```html
{% for page in 1..totalPages %}

  {% set seoUrl = seoUrl('frontend.navigation.page', { navigationId: currentNavigationId }) %}
  {# Properly encode the SEO parameters into a string before using it #}
  {% set seoParams = '?' ~ seoParams|url_encode %}
  {% if currentNavigationId is defined %}
   <a href="{{ seoUrl ~ seoParams }}" title="{{ page.header.navigation.active.translated.name }}"></a>
  {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

This works great on the first pagination page - the link title contains the translated navigation name as expected.

However, when I click to the second page or any other page, the `page.header.navigation.active.translated.name` variable is empty, so the link titles are blank.

I tried storing the name in a variable on the first page but that doesn't help on subsequent pages.

How can I dynamically populate the title attribute with the category/navigation name on each paginated page? I need a way to get that name that will work on any page, not just the first.